# Python: Local variables mysteriously update Global variables

Tags: python, variables, global, local

I have a function where I work with a local variable, and then pass back the final variable after the function is complete.  I want to keep a record of what this variable was before the function however the global variable is updated along with the local variable.  Here is an abbreviated version of my code (its quite long)

```
def Turn(P,Llocal,T,oflag):
    #The function here changes P, Llocal and T then passes those values back
    return(P, Llocal, T, oflag)

#Later I call the function
#P and L are defined here, then I copy them to other variables to save
#the initial values

P=Pinitial
L=Linitial
P,L,T,oflag = Turn(P,L,T,oflag)
```

My problem is that L and Linitial are both updated exactly when Llocal is updated, but I want Linitial to not change.  P doesn't change so I'm confused about what is happening here.  Help?  Thanks!

The whole code for brave people is here: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1e6VJnZgVqlYGgYb6X0cCIF-7-npShM7RXL9nXd_pT-o/edit

Comment: What are the types of the objects? Can you give a complete, self-contained runnable example demonstrating what you see?

Comment: P is an int and L is a list.  T is also an int, oflag is a bool.  I've only discovered this problem through IDLE's debugger, its quite subtle.  If I display the global and local variables though, I see all three of L, Linitial and Llocal changing at the same time.  I can upload the whole code here, but its a couple hundred lines.  The parts I'm worried about now start around 190 and 57.  At the moment it throws an error from line 66, but the root reason for the error is this variable updating.

Comment: Note that [PEP-8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) recommends reserving `CapWords` for class names.

Comment: @user1930726 Make a short (but runable) example that shows the issue.

Comment: next time, use http://pastebin.com/ or some tool like that to share your code. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lists are mutable. If you pass a list to a function and that function modifies the list, then you will be able to see the modifications from any other names bound to the same list.

To fix the problem try changing this line:

```
L = Linitial
```

to this:

```
L = Linitial[:]
```

This slice makes a shallow copy of the list. If you add or remove items from the list stored in `L` it will not change the list `Lintial`.

If you want to make a deep copy, use [`copy.deepcopy`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html#copy.deepcopy).

---

The same thing does not happen with `P` because it is an integer. Integers are immutable.

Comment: I've tried using copy.deepcopy and L = Linitial[:] but I'm still getting the same error as before.  I'm working through it with the debugger, I'll post back when I see whats happening. Thank you!

Comment: It works now!  I actually had to make a shallow copy twice, both when I defined Linitial and when I re-defined L.  Thank you!!

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that P and L are `names` that are `bound` to `objects`, not values themselves. When you pass them as parameters to a function, you're actually passing a copy of the binding to P and L. That means that, if P and L are mutable objects, any changes made to them will be visible outside of the function call.

You can use the [copy](http://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html) module to save a copy of the value of a name.

Comment: As a note, `copy` is a module, not a function.

Comment: I think understanding that the function receives a pointer and operates on the same object as the initial is sufficient in this case. However, immutable objects are generally copied implicity on assignment (e.g. numerics and strings) whereas mutable objects assign the same pointer to the new name and so you have two names referring to the same instance.

Comment: @Nisan.H Python the language has no notion of a 'pointer', so this isn't useful (although cPython, the implementation, does use pointers). And immutable objects are not "copied on assignment". The name is merely re-bound to whatever is being assigned to.

Answer (score 0):

In Python, a variable is just a reference to an object or value in the memory. For example, when you have a list `x`:

```
x = [1, 2, 3]
```

So, when you assign `x` to another variable, let's call it `y`, you are just creating a new reference (`y`) to the object referenced by `x` (the `[1, 2, 3]` list).

```
y = x
```

When you update `x`, you are actually updating the object pointed by `x`, i.e. the list `[1, 2, 3]`. As `y` references the same value, it appears to be updated too.

Keep in mind, variables are just references to objects.

If you really want to copy a list, you shoud do:

```
new_list = old_list[:]
```

Here's a nice explanation: http://henry.precheur.org/python/copy_list